# RestTemplate postForObject returns null, doesn't hit the service

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring `RestTemplate` for hitting a http service which works fine from a browser based HTTP client. But in my Java code, `RestTemplate` returns null. It doesn't hit the service (I tested using a debug point).

Below is my rest client code:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/webappn/app/decryptPassword";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(getConnectionPassword().toString(), headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
try{
    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, String.class);
    this.password = response;
}catch(HttpStatusCodeException e){
    utils.writeLoggerError(LOGGER, "Password could not be decrypted");
    throw new Exception("Password could not be decrypted");
}
```

`response` is coming null when this code executes.

This is the rest service code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/decryptPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
public String decryptPassword(@RequestBody String cipherText){
    try{
        return myService.decryptPassword(cipherText);
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("Password cannot be decrypted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine. Did you check your result at the endpoint? My be you got null from controller? Try to return hard coded value from controller and check response

Comment: @Maxim It is not hitting the endpoint as I have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this was happening. I have an authentication layer set up which filters all the requests. I added the `JSESSIONID` cookie in my request and it worked fine.

Although, it should have thrown an exception.